# Full Pipeline for Jenkins with Git-Flow approach by one click?

Tags: git, maven, docker, jenkins, git-flow

Using:

1. Docker
2. Java Project using maven --> JGitFlow? & Spotify?
3. Bitbucket repository

I want to apply "[A successful Git branching model by Vincent Driessen](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)" to my project with **one Jenkins Job** if it"s possible. For docker, I don't want to really focus on container-orchestration like Kubernetes, so simply at the end run the **docker-compose** on the target server.

**What do I want from the Jenkins Job:**

One jenkins job that can handle **Feature**-, **Develop**-. **Release**-, **Bugfix**-, **Hotfix**- and at the end **Master** Branch which is the actual releasing.

by building the jenkins job:

1. Build the Docker image base on the branch
2. Run the tests
3. Sonar
4. push image to the artifactory
5. run the docker-compose on target server

I know all the steps (let me know if I've missed anything), but I'm struggling how can I automated everything by one-click, specially for Releasing, because Master Branch is delivered not the Release-Branch.

The SQT has to run Release-Branch otherwise Realase-Branch doesn't make sens at all. Right?

I want to avoid as much as possible bash script.

**Edit #1**

Each branch has own target server and docker-compose